# Uneven line spacing and titlesec

Tags: xetex, fontspec, titlesec, line-spacing

I want to set the leading for chapter titles with fontspec and titlesec. Unfortunately, the first line has bigger leading than the others and I dont't know how to fix it. I read about the problem, there was suggested to end the paragraph after the chapter title. But I could not do that with titlesec. A minimal example follows:

```
\documentclass{book}

\usepackage{blindtext}
\usepackage{titlesec}
\usepackage{fontspec}

\newfontfamily\headerfont{Georgia}
\titleformat{\chapter}{\raggedright\fontsize{40}{30}\headerfont}{}{0pt}{\uppercase}

\begin{document}
\chapter{A long chapter title with multiple lines}
\blindtext
\end{document}
```

[image]

Answer (score 2):

You're asking a baseline skip of 30pt with a font size of 40pt and this is the cause for the squeezed lines. Use a larger baseline skip:

```
\documentclass{book}

\usepackage{blindtext}
\usepackage{titlesec}
\usepackage{fontspec}

\newfontfamily\headerfont{Georgia}

\titleformat{\chapter}
  {\raggedright\fontsize{40}{50}\headerfont}
  {}
  {0pt}
  {\MakeUppercase}

\begin{document}

\chapter{A long chapter title with multiple lines}

\blindtext

\end{document}
```

Avoid `\uppercase` and prefer `\MakeUppercase`.

[image]

If you want that reduced leading (I can't see any valid reason for it):

```
\documentclass{book}

\usepackage{blindtext}
\usepackage{titlesec}
\usepackage{fontspec}

\newfontfamily\headerfont{Georgia}
\titleformat{\chapter}
  {\linespread{0}\raggedright\fontsize{40}{0}\headerfont}
  {}
  {0pt}
  {\MakeUppercase}

\begin{document}
\chapter{A long chapter title with multiple lines}
\blindtext
\end{document}
```

The output is here (I labeled the edit as *horribile visu*).

[image]

Comment: But I want it that small